# Ошибка Partially initialized module 'threading' has no attribute 'Thread'

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Partially initialized module 'threading' has no attribute 'Thread' (most likely due to a circular import)

Вот такая ошибка что с ней делать из-за чего она возникает.
Возникает в любом коде даже когда не импортирую модуль ***threading***

Comment: а в папке со скриптами не валяется Thread.py ?

Comment: или threading.py

Comment: Спасибо! Большое

Comment: @Интик Напишыте в форме ответа!
P.S Чтобы люди увидели!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нельзя называть свои скрипты как модули.Thread, time, random, pygame и тд будут вызывать подобные ошибки.

для решения заданного вопроса нужно переименовать thread.py в папке со скриптами.